# h2o autoML Error in GUI and through python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o, h2o4gpu

When I am running AUTO ML through H20 GUI getting below in user feedback and no GBM/Deep learning  model got created in leaderboard. pls suggest why GBM and deeplearning failed.

24  16:18:30.768    Info    ModelTraining   GBM 2 failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class_sampling_factors must have 2 elements
25  16:18:30.768    Info    ModelTraining   GBM 3 started
26  16:18:31.768    Info    ModelTraining   GBM 3 failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class_sampling_factors must have 2 elements
32  16:18:34.795    Info    ModelTraining   Default Deep Learning build failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class_sampling_factors must have 2 elements

Also when i am trying to run automl code in python then its randomly giving below error when I am trying to convert some int fields into factor.
What does this error suggests.

H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
Server error water.util.DistributedException:
  Error: DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: '-1'
  Request: None

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message it looks like you incorrectly used the argument `class_sampling_factors`. As the message says you can only provide 2 elements. I would recommend reviewing the documentation on this parameter [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2oautoml)

In the future it would help if you provided a reproducible code snippet so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks Lauren..Actually this error i ma getting when i am running through h20 GUI interface...I gave class_sampling_factors parameter value as 1., 0.5, 1.    but getting same error. Pls suggest what should be the corrrect value for this parameter.                                When I am tring to run auml code through  python spyder interface getting  error (H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:Server error java.lang.NullPointerException: None and H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error: Server error water.util.DistributedException: Error: DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: '

Comment: @Lauren-  Please suggest

Comment: @SarvendraSingh are you no longer hitting an issue with your original question? can you post what version of H2O-3 you are using? For spyder since this is a separate question please post it as a new question - and provide enough information to reproduce the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I am using h20 version 3.22.1.2..I am using h20 GUI UI flow..So my query is what should be sample value we need to give for class_sampling_factors parameter.. Thanks.